# How do I grab a date column from a google sheet and populate it into the description of Google Calendar Event in Apps Scripts?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, format, google-calendar-api

I want to create automated google calendar events from Google Form responses that are feeding into a Google Sheet, using Google Apps Script. My issue is the date formatting - I've tried two different methods and neither resulted in the correct short date format of the date (birth date, dob) in the description of the google calendar event.

This is the code block I'm using to automate the calendar event creation from a google sheet:

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  let communityCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_cfcde4d0d89caf1ab8260da297caf663fa9b3d78533da772e481f0ebf577ce5e@group.calendar.google.com");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0,1);

  let dob = Utilities.formatDate(new Date("J2"), "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");

  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
    communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[6], entry[19], entry[20], {description: 'DOB:' + dob + '\n' + entry[10] + '\n' + entry[23] + '\n' + entry[25] });
  });
}
```

1. I tried using the function(entry) to grab the date column (entry[9]) but this resulted in the complete date format (too long).

```
  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
    communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[6], entry[19], entry[20], {description: 'DOB:' + entry[9] + '\n' + entry[10] + '\n' + entry[23] + '\n' + entry[25] });
  });
```

2. I then tried the Utilities.formatDate function and this resulted in the incorrect date, although formatted correctly.

```
  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
    communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[6], entry[19], entry[20], {description: 'DOB:' + dob + '\n' + entry[10] + '\n' + entry[23] + '\n' + entry[25] });
  });
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the date to appear *correctly* in the short date format (MM/dd/yyyy)?

Comment: Please share what your "J2" looks like or how did you get the value for J2 in forms?

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, as another approach, how about using `getValues` and `getDisplayValues`? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function createCalendarEvent() {
  // let communityCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_cfcde4d0d89caf1ab8260da297caf663fa9b3d78533da772e481f0ebf577ce5e@group.calendar.google.com");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // I modified the below script.
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const [, ...schedule] = range.getValues();
  const [, ...scheduleStr] = range.getDisplayValues();
  schedule.forEach((entry, i) => {
    communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[6], entry[19], entry[20], { description: 'DOB:' + scheduleStr[i][9] + '\n' + entry[10] + '\n' + entry[23] + '\n' + entry[25] });
  });
}
```

- In this modification, `scheduleStr[i][9]` is used as the display value of the cell value. So, it supposes that the cell value of your Spreadsheet is the formatted value you expect.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: @Camile Molina About `This worked, thank you!!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

### Change the date from the Data to MM/DD/YY

I understand you want to change the format of your date.Here is the sample code I create that you can use as a reference. Due to the limited information on your current project. It will not directly apply to you but it will get you started in getting to the right place.

### Sample Code:

```
function testFunction(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Response").getRange("A1"); // You can change it depending on your sheet. I suggest change it by using getSheetByName().
var readDate = range.getValue(); // Storing the value so you can have better grasp on the data

var dob = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(readDate), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
console.log(dob);
console.log(readDate);
}
```

[image]

The logs will show you how I transform the data from the Now() function on the "A1" range to the Date format you are looking for.

### References:

[Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)